# Fastest way to iterate and index through Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, indexing

I have an array of 50k strings called products`- and a dataframe of about 22 million rows called all

I want to iterate through the array and then select a corresponding subset of the dataframe that contains the array value:

```
for i in products:
 all.query('id == i')
```

Each query takes about 1.5s to compute, with 50k values in my array that will take me about 20 hours.

Do you know any faster way to compute this ?

Comment: `df.loc[[id]]`?

Comment: .loc is even slower

Comment: How about `all[all[id] == i]`? It seems like creating a minimal working example here would allow people to actually help here, though maybe you're best off just running your program through [line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) to see what exactly the slow part is.

Comment: Another possibility - if the slow part is all the string comparisons, it may be faster to start by sorting `all` by `id`, then using things like `np.searchsorted` to do a fast binary search for the indices you want (this way on average you'll be doing 1 sort (n log n) and 50,000 binary searches (log n), rather than 50,000 x 22M comparisons.

Comment: all[all[id] == i] takes about 3 seconds, can you give me an example on how to use searchsorted for this case please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to test this, I generated my own version of these dataframes (not sure if the statistical properties are the same, but the timing results seem similar to what you're getting):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import uuid

products = pd.Series([uuid.uuid4().hex for i in range(50000)])
all_products = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(products,
                                             size=(int(22e6),), replace=True),
                            columns=['id'])
```

**Binary search method**

One way to do this is to sort your `all` dataframe and use `searchsorted` to do the queries as binary searches - which has a one-time heavy cost sorting the 22M rows (`n log n`), but makes the lookups much faster (`log n`). This may be the fastest way to achieve your explicitly stated goal:

```
import timeit
s = timeit.default_timer()
all_products_sorted = all_products.sort_values(by='id')
e = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time to sort: {:0.5f}'.format((e - s) / N))
# Time to sort: 11.27207

N = 1000
s = timeit.default_timer()
for _, i in zip(range(N), products):
    start = all_products_sorted['id'].searchsorted(i, side='left')
    end = all_products_sorted['id'].searchsorted(i, side='right')
    x = all_products_sorted['id'].iloc[start[0]:end[0]]
e = timeit.default_timer()

print('{:0.5f}s per query'.format((e - s) / N))
# 0.00038s per query
```

So it seems that you can expect to sort the rows in around 12s, and then query the 50,000 rows in another ~20s, for a total of 32s. In my example I don't actually *save* the results, but I assume once you have the indices into the `all_products` dataframe (don't call it `all` because that's a Python builtin!), you can store them as desired.

**Groupby Method**

Another method, which (according to my test), is considerably faster if `all_products` consists *entirely* or *mostly* of values from `products` (as mine does), is to group `all_products` by `id` and dump the result into a dictionary (or whatever you want to do with it):

```
s = timeit.default_timer()
x_dict = {k: v for k, v in all_products.groupby('id')}
e = timeit.default_timer()
print('{:0.5f}s per query'.format((e - s) / len(products)))
# 0.00032s per query
```

Note that in this case it is apparently faster than the `searchsorted` method (though not considerably), *and* doesn't require the input to be sorted in the first place.

Note that if what you actually want to do is transform these rows or modify them in some way, in this case `groupby` is definitely the way to go - don't even bother dumping to a dictionary, instead see the [split-apply-combine page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) for strategies on working with Dataframes in this way.

**Naive methods**

For comparison, here are two approaches that involve full searches:

```
import timeit
N = 5
s = timeit.default_timer()
for _, i in zip(range(N), products):
    x = all_products.query('id == "{}"'.format(i))
e = timeit.default_timer()

print('{:0.5f}s per query'.format((e - s) / N))  # 1.60075s per query


s = timeit.default_timer()
for _, i in zip(range(N), products):
    x = all_products[all_products['id'] == i]
e = timeit.default_timer()

print('{:0.5f}s per query'.format((e - s) / N))  # 3.00135s per query
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your long and detailed answer, I finally used the groupby method this is by far the fastest if you want to do manipulations after !

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select all rows with ids in the products list, this should be much faster than a for loop:

```
import numpy as np    
df[np.in1d(df.id,products)]
```

Comment: I want to execute operations inside the iterations so for example with the product 'Chocolate' I want to select all rows that contain the product chocolate and perform operations on those rows